# XML serialisation error when connecting to XMPP server

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire, sharp.xmpp

I have an instance of OpenFIre up and running and all is pretty smooth. I can connect to it via Spark as well as a variety of app.

When I wrote my app using the trial version of the Matrix SDK, the client connected perfectly. I am trying to move over to Sharp.XMPP and yet, whenever I try to connect to the server, I get the following error message :

> The XML stream could not be negotiated.

When I drill down, I get to the folllwoing inner exception

> {"'�', hexadecimal value 0x15, is an invalid character. Line 1,
>   position 1."}

There seems to be some issue with the response encoding that Sharp.XMPP is expecting.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect to an old-style SSL port (usually 5223) with a client that expects to do StartTLS (usually on 5222)?

(`0x15` is the TLS content type for "alert", which is likely the response when parsing something that is not TLS.)

Comment: I explicitly tell it to use SSL so I am not sure why it is receiving TLS data

Comment: To what port number are you connecting?

Comment: Don't use 5223 and make sure your DNS SVR Records doesn't have port 5223 in them. Make use of https://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns/ if it still works